# using load method in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

have an index page that i intend to use for as the central hub for my application contained in another folder is a file ./php/createForm.php which is a form for users to fill out...what i am trying to achieve is clicking "create new" from the menu bar(found in ethics) & then using the .load() method i could bring it to my index page ...as a form of debugging to see if my code works, i want it to alert() when the send button is clicked...however, it just refreshes...how can i properly load the form and allow it to perform its function without retarting?

student.php

```
<?
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#usertab").html("<? echo $_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname']; ?><b class=\"caret\"></b>");
    $('#create-New').click(function() {

        $(".bs-example").load("./php/createForm.php");
    });
    $("#send").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("eudjk");
    });
    //alert("dfjdfk ");
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">College Logo</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ethics Form <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a id="create-New">Create New</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">View Submitted</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li><!--end of .dropdown-->

        <li class="active dropdown" >
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="usertab"> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Logout &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="bs-example" style="margin-top:150px;">


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

createForm.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title panel-active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">User Details</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fullname">Researcher</label>
                                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="form-control input-disable" id="fullname" placeholder="e.g Mike Oksmall ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Ben Debanana@yahoo.com"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Title">Title of Project/Dessertation</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Insert Title Here"/>
                            </div>

                    </div><!--end of panel-body for user details-->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end of user details panel-->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Project Aims and Design Overview</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="project-aim">Aim of Project</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="project-Aim" placeholder="Insert Project Aim">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="overview">Design Overview</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control overview" id="overview" placeholder="Project Overview">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>                 


                    </div><!--end of panel-body for Aim of Project-->
                </div>
            </div><!--end of panel-->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Participants</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="advice">Number of Participants</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control advice" id="no-participants" placeholder="State the nature of any advice received in planning the project">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="procedure">Method Of Selection For Participants</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control procedure" id="procedure" placeholder="Procedure on participants">
                            </textarea>
                         </div>

                    </div><!--end of panel-body for participants-->
                </div>
            </div><!--end of panel for participants-->
           <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">Research</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="advice">Nature and Source of Methodlogical Advice</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control advice" id="advice" placeholder="State the nature of any advice received in planning the project">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="procedure">Procedure  Carried out on Participants</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control procedure" id="procedure" placeholder="Procedure on participants">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="risk">Potential Risks to participants and measures</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control risk" id="procedure" placeholder="Procedure on participants">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="risk">Potential Risks to Researchers and measures</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control risk" id="procedure" placeholder="Procedure on participants">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="consent">How will the records of Consent be Saved?</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control consent" id="consent" placeholder="Procedure on participants">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="findings">How will the findings of this research be disseminated?</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control findings" id="findings" value="Procedure on participants">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--end of panel-->

            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 send " type="submit">Send Form <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>
                    </div>

        </div>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you opened developers console? Are there any errors?

Comment: @u_mulder i dont see any

Comment: `#create-New` is a link. Add `preventDefault` or `return false` to prevent default action.

Comment: @u_mulder i tried both and they work....however, the menu bar stops working